# General Chern number question.

Tags: algebraic-topology

In physics we often define the Chern number as the closed integral over the Berry curvature $$\Omega_{xy}=\frac{\partial A_x}{\partial k_y}-\frac{\partial A_x}{\partial k_x}.$$
With, 
$$A_i(\mathbf{k})=i\langle \psi_{\mathbf{k}}|\partial_{k_i}|\psi_{\mathbf{k}}\rangle.$$
So, we are often interested in,
$$C=\frac{1}{2\pi}\oint_{}\Omega_{xy} d^2k,$$
where the Chern number is a closed integral over all momentum in the Brillouin zone.

My question is: **What is a Chern number generally?** 
Is it simply the integral over a closed surface such that the result is invariant in certain regions of the parameter space? I often see meantions of Chern classes, how are they related to Chern numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If M is an closed oriented $2n$-manifold,  a Chern number of $M$ is simply the integral of any product of Chern classes of its tangent bundle which has total degree $2n$.

Comment: Could you elaborate on Chern classes and tangent bundles for someone who is not familiar with those kinds of things? Or point me to some nice source for this information.

Comment: Tangent bundles are explained in every textbook on manifolds. Lee's book, for example, is particularly great. As for Chern classes, I suggest Husemoller's book and/or the one by Stasheff (but if you do not knw what the tangent bundle is I doubt either could be of much use, really)

Comment: One more question. If a Chern number is an integral of any product of Chern classes of a manifold's tangent bundle, then, is the thing that appears in my integral such a product? Is the Berry curvature a product of Chern classes?

Comment: It is a product of 1 class.

Comment: Cool. I think your information is helpfull. Thank you very much.